# Postgresql: How do I set the password for the user 'postgres' when I can't access the postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I'm running postgresql 10.12 on Ubuntu 18.04.

I'd like to experiment with a software package that uses postgres. This means I should figure out how to set up users, passwords and databases under postgres.

Postgres is running, but there's no way to log in to it.

I'm pretty sure there is a user called 'postgres'.

Logging in as this user without providing a password fails.
Also, attempting to use the passwords 'postgres' or 'root' fail.

How do I change the password for the user 'postgres' without being able to access the database?

Comment: Typically the operating system user `postgres` is allowed to log in without a password. See [client authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/client-authentication.html) in the manual.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is a newbie-level recipe to reset the superuser password, which works on all fresh installations of PostgreSQL on Linux.

1. Go to the shell and switch user to `postgres`

   ```
    (in user shell) sudo su - postgres
   ```
2. connect to the `postgres` database as `postgres` user

   ```
    (in postgres shell) psql postgres postgres
   ```
3. now you can reset password of `postgres` user

   ```
    (in postgres psql) ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'newsecret';
   ```
4. quit psql

   ```
    (in postgres psql) \q
   ```
5. quit postgres shell

   ```
    (in postgres shell) exit
   ```
6. test connection with new password

   ```
    (in user shell) psql -h localhost postgres postgres
   ```

**Note on remote postgres servers**

In step 1 above, you can use `ssh`, `kubectl exec`, `aws ssm` or anything like that, if you have this kind of shell access.

### Best Practice note

Above recipe (though it answers the OP question) is not a good practice. The best approach is:

1. Read and understand client auth -> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/client-authentication.html
2. **Do not use `postgres` database user (or any other superuser!) for applications/development.** Create your own user instead. For the simplest setup, use this:

   ```
    (in psql shell)
    CREATE USER myapp PASSWORD 'secret';
    CREATE DATABASE myapp;
    ALTER DATABASE myapp OWNER TO myapp;
    -- alternative if you want to keep default ownership:
    -- GRANT ALL ON DATABASE myapp TO myapp;
   ```

   This should be done instead of modifying `postgres` user and/or `postgres` database.

**Note on Managed postgres solutions**

This answer applies only for self-managed PostgreSQL, where you have superuser shell access. It will not work for managed solutions like Aurora, CloudSQL or alike - use cloud provider tools to reset db passwords in that case.